# Is there a way to do a keydown forEach event?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to set up an accessibility feature for this bootstrap accordion. I added in the `tabindex=0` to each `<a>` tag and I'm trying to ensure that if the user hits tab it will open up that corresponding dropdown/accordion. But as of now my code opens every single accordion option when the user hit the tab button. Is there a way to do a `forEach` on keydown?

```js
$('.accordion-toggle').keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    $('.collapse').addClass('show');
  } else {
    $('.collapse').removeClass('show')
  }
});
```

```html
<a 
  class="text-left w-100 btn btn-link accordion-toggle" 
  tabindex="0" 
  data-toggle="collapse" 
  data-target="#collapseEight" 
  aria-expanded="true" 
  aria-controls="collapseEight">
    item 1 <i class="arrow down"></i>
</a>

       <div id="collapseSeven" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingSeven" data-parent="#accordion">
        <p> Content for this section</p>
        </div>
<a 
  class="text-left w-100 btn btn-link accordion-toggle" 
  tabindex="0" 
  data-toggle="collapse" 
  data-target="#collapseEight" 
  aria-expanded="true" 
  aria-controls="collapseEight">
    item 2 <i class="arrow down"></i>
</a>


       <div id="collapseSeven" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingSeven" data-parent="#accordion">
        <p> Content for this section</p>
        </div>
```

Comment: Instead of adding `show` to all `.collapse` elements, add it to the element that triggered the event: `$(this).addClass('show');`

Comment: The problem with adding 'this' is the class being added shouldnt be for the a tag (which is what 'this' would be referring to). it's being added to the div under it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this was what you were after, but...  If the tab key is pressed, then:

- a small delay is set to allow the document to shift the tabindex focus
- if the element focused on is an accordion control, then all accordions are collapsed, then the one that corresponds to the control's `data-target` is expanded.

```js
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  //console.log(e.keyCode)
  if (e.keyCode == 9) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      let $focused = $(':focus');
      if ($focused.hasClass('accordion-toggle')) {
        //close all open ones
        $('.collapsed').removeClass('show');
        $($focused.data('target')).addClass('show')
      }
    }, 50)
  }
});
```

```css
.collapsed {
  display: none;
}

.collapsed.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="text-left w-100 btn btn-link accordion-toggle" tabindex="0" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseEight" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseEight">
    item 1 <i class="arrow down"></i>
</a>
<div id='collapseEight' class='collapsed'>Text from collapseEight</div>
<a class="text-left w-100 btn btn-link accordion-toggle" tabindex="0" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseNine" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseNine">
    item 2 <i class="arrow down"></i>
</a>


<div id='collapseNine' class='collapsed'>Text from collapseNine</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use  document.activeElement, which will only act on selected accordion then find the right accordion parent and select the collapse element within it.. and you need to run the keydown on document level and check if the focus item is the accordion item, below solution is mix of pure Javascript and jQuery:

```
$(document).keydown(function(){
    let focused = document.activeElement;
    const pattern = /(?:^|\s)accordion-toggle(?:\s|$)/
    if (document.activeElement.className.match(pattern)) {
        $('.collapse').removeClass('show'); 
        let element = document.activeElement;
        $(element).closest('.accordion-item').find('.collapse').addClass('show');
    }
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/k86fj5ex/